# How to handle absolute values in gurobi

Tags: python, gurobi

I am trying to implement a linear optimisation problem in gurobi for a portfolio optimisation problem.
Say you have the expected returns of 48 stocks across 120 days. The initial price of each stock is $10. What I did was try to get the prices of the stocks for each day by cumulatively multiply the initial price with each day's returns.

My goal now is then to maximise the portfolio's returns on the 120th day. To do that, I have created a few variables

bought -> 121 x 48 matrix to track how many stocks were bought or sold. Positive value means bought while negative means sold

holding -> 121 x 48 matrix how many of each stock were held in day i

portfolio_value -> 121 x 1 vector how much the portfolio is worth in day i

cash -> 121x1 vector how much cash was leftover in day i

There is a 2% transaction cost on the total value transacted on day i. Hence I also created a variable to track everyday's transaction cost

transaction -> 121x1 vector on transaction cost for day i

The main constraint for this problem is that for every period, we will need to ensure that each stock holds at least 1% of the total portfolio value (all the stocks +cash).

With that, I was able to formulate this on gurobi

```
#data
num_periods = 121 #first period no trade
num_stocks = 48
starting_capital = 100000
diversification_constraint = 0.01
transaction_cost = 0.02
estimated_prices = price
# Create model
m = gp.Model('Portfolio Optimization')

# Create variables
bought = m.addVars(num_periods, num_stocks, vtype=gp.GRB.INTEGER, name='bought')
holding = m.addVars(num_periods, num_stocks, vtype=gp.GRB.INTEGER, name='holding')
transaction = m.addVars(num_periods, name='transaction')
portfolio_value = m.addVars(num_periods, name='portfolio_value')
cash = m.addVars(num_periods, name='cash')

# Set objective
m.setObjective(portfolio_value[num_periods-1], gp.GRB.MAXIMIZE)

# Set constraints
# Starting cash constraint: starting cash should be equal to starting capital
m.addConstr(cash[0] == starting_capital)

# Starting bought and holding constraint: In period 0, no stocks were bought or held
m.addConstrs((bought[0, j] == 0 for j in range(num_stocks)))
m.addConstrs((holding[0, j] == 0 for j in range(num_stocks)))

# Bought = holding this period - holding last period
m.addConstrs((bought[i, j] == holding[i, j] - holding[i-1, j] for i in range(1, num_periods) for j in range(num_stocks)))

# Transaction cost constraint: 
m.addConstrs((transaction[i] == transaction_cost * gp.quicksum(gp.abs_(bought[i,j]).getValue() * estimated_prices[i,j] for j in range(num_stocks))) for i in range(1, num_periods))

# Portfolio value constraint
m.addConstrs((portfolio_value[i] == gp.quicksum(holding[i, j] * estimated_prices[i,j] for j in range(num_stocks)) + cash[i]) for i in range(num_periods))

# Cash balance constraint
m.addConstrs((cash[i] == cash[i-1] - transaction[i] - gp.quicksum(bought[i,j] * estimated_prices[i,j] for j in range(num_stocks))) for i in range(1, num_periods))

# Diversification constraint
m.addConstrs((gp.quicksum(holding[i, j] * estimated_prices[i,j] for j in range(num_stocks)) >= diversification_constraint * portfolio_value[i]) for i in range(num_periods))

# Solve model
m.optimize()

# Print solution
if m.status == gp.GRB.OPTIMAL:
    print('Optimal solution found!')
    print('Final portfolio value:', portfolio_value[num_periods-1].x)
else:
    print('No solution found.')
```

However I kept getting this error from python. AttributeError: 'GenExprAbs' object has no attribute 'getValue'
This error comes from the transaction cost constraint where I used gp.abs_ to convert all the values in **bought** to positive values because regardless of whether you buy or sell the stock in our case, transaction cost will be applicable. Could y'all find a workaround for this?

However I kept getting this error from python. AttributeError: 'GenExprAbs' object has no attribute 'getValue'
This error comes from the transaction cost constraint where I used gp.abs_ to convert all the values in **bought** to positive values because regardless of whether you buy or sell the stock in our case, transaction cost will be applicable. Could y'all find a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Reason is explained [here](https://support.gurobi.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360073645412-Abs-Value) & for proper use, [here](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/9.0/refman/py_abs_.html).
Need to define a new auxillary variable like

```
abs_cost = m.addVars(i,j)
m.addConstrs(abs_cost[i,j] == abs_(bought[i,j) for i,j in..)
m.addConstrs(transaction_cost[i] =abs_cost[i,j]*...)
```